# How can I recover the COMPIZ COLOR FILTER PLUGIN in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: compiz, 12.10

I had the `COMPIZ COLOR FILTER` plug-in in my Ubuntu 12.04 then I upgraded to 12.10 and now it disappeared.

Comment: I have reported a bug in Ubuntu here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz-plugins-main/+bug/1093565

Answer (score 3):

I was able to modify the Neg plugin to turn it into Color Filter. Please read more here http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12395466&postcount=19

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent quite some time in trying to get the compiz color plugin to work. It's not easy because the compiz version that is bundled with Ubuntu has had major changes to it which makes it difficult to compile / rewrite the color filter plugin.

In the meanwhile, I have found `xcalib`, using which one can filter away colors.

`xcalib -clear && xcalib -green 1 1 50 -blue 1 1 50 -alter`

The 50 is the percentage of how much you would like the color to pass through. If you want only 20% of green and blue to show through, you can use:

`xcalib -clear && xcalib -green 1 1 20 -blue 1 1 20 -alter`

To reset everything to original display one can use:

`xcalib -clear`

I have written a [script](https://gist.github.com/hrj/6561271) to wrap these commands into a nice little utility.

**Advantages of xcalib over compiz**:

- It affects the entire screen. The compiz-color filter didn't apply automatically to newly created windows and special windows (such as popups, notifications, sys tray, etc).

**Disadvantages**:

- There is no way to disable xcalib for a particular window.
- The compiz color filter allowed custom algorithms for filtering.